# Automatically correct opened queries and database connections

Tags: database, delphi, runtime, design-time

Sometimes connections to database and queries are left open in design time by human error and saved in the dfm.
I was thinking about a code to avoid that kind of mistake by auto closing those connections and queries before they try to auto-open on its creation...

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a feature of the GExperts IDE extension: "Set component properties" see http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?setcomponentproperties.html

Comment: thanks... good to know. I still prefer to no install anything, if possible I will go by some code. But this will be my second option!

Comment: You could probably do this by writing an IDE add-in package using OTA + the ToolsAPI unit, but if the GExperts extension does what you want, why bother?

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat *(Delphi)* in the title of your post.  The tag system works extremely well here, so adding a Delphi tag is sufficient. Redundantly putting it in the title is unnecessary clutter. Thanks.

Comment: @MartynA Actually I was wondering if it would be possible to write a code (class helper for example) that would do that without having to deal with the IDE or .DFM for example... Just to prevent the auto-opening in the creation of a dataset / connection

Comment: I imagine a class helper might help, but it would need to be capable of being invoked on the instance of the dataset or connection that is created by the IDE at design time.  So (I'm guessing that) the class helper would be to be compiled into a design time package to be invokable via the IDE.  Interesting.  I may look into it tomorrow and do an experiment or two.

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass your connection component and setup the `Connected`property so it never is written to the DFM.
This means that a developer can set the connection property to "True" in designtime and does not have to worry it will be left open at runtime.

Example for the TAdoConnection :

```
type
  TggAdoConnection = class(TADOConnection)
  published
    property Connected stored false;
  end;
```